# Efficient way to copy and paste address into web form, fill forms

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, automation

A repetitive task I would like to automate is moving address data from one website to a form on a different website.

Currently I copy the name, paste the name, copy the first address line, paste the first address line, copy the... you get the idea. I like using Chrome, OSX. It's important enough that it needs human confirmation, and I'd like to see what's happening.

A related sub-question is how to repetitively fill out forms. I use 1Password for logins, but a similar tool for just ticking saved radio buttons—especially if it could fill out some fields with information from the first website would be very useful.

Comment: Is the destination website a public site? If so can you give us the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple answer.

1. Open Terminal.app
2. Enter this command

> `man curl`

3. Read and imagine the possibilities

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use 1Password to save any form as a "Login" item. Some people do this to easily submit sweepstakes forms daily, or other repetitive tasks like that. After you've filled out your form, just click the 1Password extension, click the gear icon, and select "Save New Login" and you should be able to restore that Login item on that website in the future, even if it's not really a "login" form.